# How can i unhide javascript and html errors hidden by filters in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I hide the *JavaScript* and *HTML* errors from console but it finds difficult job for me unhide them again.

**How can unhide them again?**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking this. The answers below helped, but chrome has changed its interface since they were written, and it is in a slightly different place. Why the facility exists to hide errors, that is why you would want to hide errors in a tool you use to debug code is beyond me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the left side, change the filter selection :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ummp4.png)

Comment: it already set to info see in the screenshot in question @Laurent Plantrose

Comment: I saw that ^^ but did you try to put it to Errors or another one ?

Comment: Try changing to "Default levels"

Comment: Laurent: can you fix the screenshot? It's not showing.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem by doing these steps:

1. Select **Console**.
2. **Right click**.
3. Move to **Filter** and
4. Then select **unhide all**.

[image: Put Image]

Comment: 'unhide all' is grayed out to me (disabled)

Comment: If 'Unhide all' is disabled, change the Filter to "Default levels" from "Hide all" (see Laurent Plantrose's answer)

Answer (score 0):

After click on the icon of open issues, it will be show but hide from the screen. You can see it here.[image]

To view, select the divider and move it up:
[image]